# How to use foreach loops with while-loops

Tags: c#, foreach, while-loop

I have a while loop that continues to pull data from a query until the query returns no more results, within this the for each loop populates each returned data into an xml file.
The query has a limit of 500 results per query so I wanted to return 500 results populate them and query again for the next 500 until the query return code < 1 (no results)

I am tracking the id and using this in the query to get the logic, however once the first 500 results return the loop does not get the next 500.

What I am doing wrong?

code:

```
bool is_finished = false;
while (is_finished == false)
{
    string current_id = "0";
    sb.Append("<queryxml><entity>Account</entity><query><field>AccountNumber<expression op='greaterthan'>" + current_id + "</expression></field></query></queryxml>").Append(System.Environment.NewLine);
    var r = client.query(at_integrations, sb.ToString());
    if (r.ReturnCode == 1)
    {

        foreach (var item in r.EntityResults) // max EntityResults 500 per query
        {
            Account acct = (Account)item;
            //create xml file with the results
            current_id = acct.id.ToString();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        is_finished = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: yes sorry I put <1 but when no results return it is actually -1

Answer (score 1):

You have the definition of `current_id` within your loop, each iteration it will reset it to zero.

You should debug this, you could quite easily add `Debug.WriteLine(sb);` to see the contents and you'd see that it would always return the same (note that `current_id` is always 0):

```
<queryxml><entity>Account</entity><query><field>AccountNumber<expression op='greaterthan'>0</expression></field></query></queryxml>
```

Here's updated code, which simply moves the definition of `current_id` out of the loop, so that it can be updated and the value will stick.

```
bool is_finished = false;
string current_id = "0";
while (is_finished == false)
{
    sb.Append("<queryxml><entity>Account</entity><query><field>AccountNumber<expression op='greaterthan'>" + current_id + "</expression></field></query></queryxml>").Append(System.Environment.NewLine);
    var r = client.query(at_integrations, sb.ToString());
<snip>
```

Comment: Thank you for correcting the silly mistake, I am still having no look returning the next 500 results however, the current_id does change with each loop, but once the first 500 results are returned the loop closes